# Creating a specific item and list them

Tags: lists, itemize

I'm currently using MS Word for my literature review report, but I'm not a fan of it and would like to utilize LaTeX. I used LaTeX in the past for my study or lab reports but my knowledge is no where near to answer this problem.

What I'm looking for is something like this:

[image]

I want to create a custom element "article" which I can declare its abstract goal method etc. And maybe call them in the list that I create.

Any help would be appreciated.

Health and safety for all of you!
Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear to me just what you want, but try along the following lines.

```
% litrevprob.tex  SE literature review report

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Template title (...)}
\begin{abstract}
The abstract.
\end{abstract}
\begin{description}
\item[Goal] goal
\item[Method] method
\item[Highlights] \mbox{}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Parts
  \item Others
  \end{itemize}
\item[Remarks] Some
\end{description}

\section{Title of template (...)}
\begin{abstract}
The abstract.
\end{abstract}
\begin{description}
\item[Goal] goal
\item[Method] method
\item[Highlights] \mbox{}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Parts
  \item Others
  \end{itemize}
\item[Remarks] Some
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can I try to elaborate more into my question? The final structure I'm trying to reach is something like in the screenshot I added. I will try this now. Thanks a lot

Comment: It works like a charm. I was imagining more of like a OOP idea that is why I described it so terribly. Thanks a lot for your time, Cheers.